# Troubleshooting range on Lora Radio

Tags: antenna, antenna-construction

I am using these Adafruit LoRa radio microcontrollers: [M0 radio](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/adafruit-industries-llc/3178/6098603)
paired with these parts to make up the antenna system:
[antenna](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/molex/2161960011/13684011)
[connector](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/hirose-electric-co-ltd/U.FL-R-SMT-1(01)/3978494)
[cable](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/pulselarsen-antennas/W9006/2267902)

And for some reason I am unable to get much further than 50 meters away before I am out of range.
When I use a simple 3 inch strand of wire to create an antenna, I am able to get about 200 meters of range.
These parts appear to be compatible with each other, but I am obviously missing something here.

I have double-checked that the connector is soldered to the board by doing a continuity test from the connector to the end of the coax cable, and there is perfect continuity.
I will post my entire code if it's helpful, but I feel at this point it is something hardware related because the simple 3 inch whip antenna somehow works 4 times better than the purchased antenna.

Here are the important sections of the code:

```
#include <RH_RF95.h>
#include <RHReliableDatagram.h>
#define RFM95_CS 8
#define RFM95_RST 4
#define RFM95_INT 3
#define RF95_FREQ 915.0

RH_RF95 rf95(RFM95_CS, RFM95_INT);
RHDatagram manager(rf95, SERVER_ID);

void init_radio(void)
{
  pinMode(RFM95_RST, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, HIGH);

  // manual reset
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, LOW);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(RFM95_RST, HIGH);
  delay(10);

  while (!manager.init()) 
  {
    Serial.println("LoRa radio init failed");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("LoRa radio init OK");

  if (!rf95.setFrequency(RF95_FREQ)) {
    Serial.println("setFrequency failed");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.print("Set Freq to: "); Serial.println(RF95_FREQ);

  rf95.setTxPower(23, false);
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same antenna polarities (vertical vs. horizontal, etc.) and ground plane (or lack thereof) in all cases?

Comment: I have both antennas vertical. One of them is about 2 feet from the ground, and the other is about 6 feet off the ground. Will that make a very big difference? I can try and get them on the same elevation and see.

Comment: You might want to add those details, and any other differences, to your question.  Those differences in antenna positioning, and ground counterpose, could be significant.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!